# Jenkins: same Workspace for all Projects

Tags: jenkins

I'm working on a quite complex Jenkins installation (v2.19.2) and there's something odd in it.

When clicking on a View, then on any Project, then on any Job, then on its Workspace, I am *always* returned the home directory of the Linux user `jenkins`.
This unless the Job has never been run, in which case I get an error

> A project won't have any workspace until at least one build is performed.

even although, as said, the Workspace is always the same for all Projects.

Is this a normal way to configure Jenkins? I thought every Project is supposed to have its own Workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your job configuration and see if '*Use custom workspace*' option under '*Advanced Project Options*' is checked. If checked, see if the '*Directory*' field is set to the same directory for all the jobs.

Either uncheck the '*Use custom workspace*' option or give different directories for each job.

Comment: Where can I find *"Advanced Project Options"*?

Comment: Click on your view -> Any Project -> Any Job -> Configure (on left side menu). In your configuration page, scroll down until you find 'Advanced Project Options'. Click on the advanced button to the right, it will display more options. And you can see 'Use custom workspace' option

Comment: Ah yes, it's in General, clicking on the second Advanced button. Not very easy to find.

Comment: "Use custom workspace" is unchecked for all projects. Why then is Jenkins using the same workspace instead of the default one (different for every project)?

Comment: Check in your jenkins configuration page
Go to Jenkins Homepage -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. Check the first field Home directory. Click on the first advanced button on the right side. Can you tell me what is in "Workspace Root Directory" field?

Comment: Workspace Root Directory is `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace`.

Comment: Isnt it 'Build Record Root Directory' field that you are referring to? My ' 
Workspace Root Directory' should be `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`

Variable explanation:
`${ITEM_ROOTDIR} — Root directory of a job for which the default workspace is allocated.
${ITEM_FULL_NAME} — '/'-separated job name, like "foo/bar".`

Comment: No, Workspace Root Directory is `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace`as I wrote earlier. Build Record Root Directory is `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds`.

Comment: Try changing Workspace Root Directory to `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}` and run your job

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in the statement that every project is supposed to have its own workspace.

If you have chose the default path, this will be same.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs

All your project are mentioned in job, and each will have their own workspace.

Alternatively,you can select custom workspace.